# spring-cloud-dataflow skipper does not recognize deployed streams after upgrade

Tags: kubernetes-helm, spring-cloud-dataflow, skipper

After upgrading spring-cloud-dataflow skipper
from

```
springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:2.4.1.RELEASE
```

to

```
bitnami/spring-cloud-skipper:2.8.3-debian-10-r4
```

I see that my previously DEPLOYED streams are not recognized by skipper and show the UNDEPLOYED status in the server ui.
Although the apps remained deployed in the kubernetes cluster.
Now I wounder if the data structure changed that skipper uses to store its information about deployments?
Since my upgrade is a rather huge jump and also the helm chart changed from springcloud to bitnami I wonder where to find a changelog for the skipper?

Comment: Dumb question, but you ensured the MySQL/MariaDB instance is the same?  Worse case scenario you can delete the deployments with kubectl and redeploy.

Comment: @fidim yes, valid question :) 
I have postgresql as RDBMS which is the same. I suspect that the new skipper version brings some schema changes with it - I just dont know how to verify that assumption